# Migrating from SVN 1.5 on win to SVN 1.7 on RHEL

Tags: svn

Good people of Stackoverflow,

I need your advise on the following please...

I am currently running Collabnet SVN 1.5 with apache 2.2 on a windows box and plan to migrate to SVN 1.7 on RHEL 6.
Have looked at http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/linux.html and Wandisco's vanila SVN binaries.

Does anyone has experiance on installing/configuring any of these binaries - which one would you recommend?
What would be the best process to follow for this migration?
Also, anything else that I should take care of, given that I'm moving from Win to Linux environment?

Cheers,
Savinder

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else finding this question from search, there are instructions for getting started using the WANdisco binaries [here](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/05/30/introduction-to-apache-subversion/).